# What is the lifetime of JNI localrefs for C++ calling Java?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

When Java is calling into a C function via JNI, we know that any local references to classes or objects may become invalid once the C function returns to java.

However when we only have C calling into Javam there is no "return to java". So it's not clear to me when these references will become invalid.

For example this is **bad** since `aClass`, and `anObject` will potentially become invalid once the call is complete.

```
jclass aClass;
jobject anObject;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_example_method1(JNIEnv *env) {
    aClass = env->FindClass("AClass");
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_example_method2(JNIEnv * env) {
    jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID( aClass, "<init>", "()V");
    anObject = env->NewObject(klass, constructor );
}
```

However in the following example, what can cause `aClass` and `anObject` to become invalid? Is it only an explicit call to `DeleteLocalRef`?

```
jclass aClass;
jobject anObject;

int main() {
        JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
        JavaVMOption options[1];
        vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
        vm_args.nOptions = 1;
        options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
        vm_args.options = options;
        vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;
        JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);

        aClass = env->FindClass("AClass");
        jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID( aClass, "<init>", "()V");
        anObject = env->NewObject(klass, constructor );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. When Java calls JNI it allocates a table where local refs to, that are all released when the JNI returns. Wen you're calling Java there is no such mechanism.

Comment: It's a good idea to bracket your Java calls with a `PushLocalFrame`/`PopLocalFrame` pair, which will automatically clean up any references generated.

Comment: I _think_ this is correct, but is there a reference you know of to back it up?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Not sure what you're looking for here. The first part is stated in [JNI Specification, Global and Local References: Implementing Local References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp1242), but you knew that. The second part is merely obvious.

Answer (score 0):

> Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call,
>   and are automatically freed after the native method returns.
>   Global references remain valid until they are explicitly freed.

and

> Local references are only valid in the thread in which they are created.

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp1242)